# Large circuit board options

Tags: pcb

I am making a large prototype of a device that requires a large PCB (about 15x20inches).
I am able to etch my own circuit board in copper laminates, but I cannot find large enough laminates.

Is there a good source of buying large copper laminate? Is there a way to make my own out of copper foil?

I have checked Alibaba and aliexpress and they only have a few suppliers that make laminates that big.

Comment: 18x24 inches is probably the most common panel size used in commercial board shops. How you would buy these things as a hobbyist, I couldn't tell you.

Comment: I would be looking for a way to break that up into smaller boards, or manufacturing costs will be astronomical.

Answer (score 1):

Try directly contacting a PCB fabricator.  They usually buy large pieces like this to allow making bulk multi-up boards.  They might give you a good price on some surplus they have.  They would normally buy in large quantities due to their high volume of  manufacturing.  Trying to buy small quantities yourself from the OEM would likely be very cost prohibitive.

In a few years you might be able to use a conductive ink printer to make a PCB, similar to using a 3D printer of today.  These are just starting to be available.

Answer (score 1):

Laminate is actually manufactured in large sheets on huge presses (at least 1m^2) similar to plywood and other sheet materials. If you're seeing small panels, they've almost surely been cut up from larger sheets unless they're some exotic material.

It's not hard to buy medium size pieces of laminate, but getting a good price may not be easy, and shipping something that large will (especially internationally) will tend to be expensive. Since you're using Imperial measure, if you're in the USofA you could go to McMaster, but they want $42 for a 2' x 3' piece of material.

You might have to contact a local PCB maker and beg them to sell you some, or beg a wholesaler to cut down a big sheet so it can be shipped at a reasonable price.